# Java answers - using JUnit assertions rather than System.out.println

Tags: discussion, answers

Where appropriate, I've started trying to give answers to Java questions using JUnit's `Assert` rather than `System.out.println` - such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3465472/formatnumber-how-to-add-2-decimal-digits-at-the-back-of-numbers/3466110#3466110) one.

To me it seems a bit better for providing more robust answers, and introducing perhaps more professional ways of evaluating variables rather than `System.out`.

I was just interested to see what people thought about this. Is providing JUnit just being a bit OTT (perhaps saying "I'm better than you" - which I'm not trying to do), and perhaps just clouding the issue, or is it promoting values such as test driven development?

Comment: you should ask that question on http://stackoverflow.com You are currently on Meta.stackoverflow.com.  This is not a place to ask programming questions.

Comment: @jjnguy - I'm not asking a programming question - I'm asking about the *approach* to answering questions.

Comment: oops, my bad...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is a great way to provide "executable answers", that can be easily verified. In fact, all the code samples in the Groovy in Action book use this approach.

However, I think using the Java `assert` keyword is even better than using JUnit's assert. Functionally, the two are almost identical, but you remove a dependency on a framework by using the Java assert instead.

Comment: I like this answer, and have voted it up. However - Java's `assert` keyword only allows `boolean` values. JUnit's `Assert` is a little more descriptive in my opinion, such as `assertNotNull` or `assertEqual`. I know that you can make these into `boolean` statements, but it just seems a little clearer, especially someone who is new to the language - this describes exactly what is going on IMO.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the question, but mostly I would prefer `System.out.println` to show results and JUnit only if the question involves testing or is about using JUnit itself.

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3465472/formatnumber-how-to-add-2-decimal-digits-at-the-back-of-numbers/3466110#3466110), in particular, I think it's not very helpful - probably the OP does not know what `assertEquals` is for and it is just introducing another difficulty. It's not directly saying the result of *that command* is *this result*. Despite the need to include another library/API.

Sample code should be complete but simple IMO.

Answer (score -1):

I think here we have three different concepts we need to discern between: unit tests, `System.out.println()` and the [assert](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/lang/assert.html) keyword. Unit testing is a systematic way to tell whether an application behaves as expected especially when some modifications of the source code are made. Personally, I'm in favor of the following software design strategy:

1. Create Interfaces and implementing classes with out body (throwing UnsupportedOperationException)
2. Create unit tests
3. Implement the interfaces
4. Run the JUnit tests

And run the unit tests every now and then to check if everything is as expected. Unit tests should be exhaustive and leave little space for bugs. I point I would like to clarify is that using JUnit does not add an extra dependency in the distribution of your application but exists only locally. Such dependencies are known as "test libraries". Including such libraries (e.g. JUnit or DbUnit) in your classpath is really not recommendable either if you work on a library (so you oblige your clients to have this dependency in their main classpath) or on a standalone executable application such as a GUI (because your executable jar will be larger in size). For example, among people working with maven it is well known that JUnit should be declared as a `test` dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>${junit.version}</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

The keyword `assert` now, though can be used for testing, its scope is different; assert is a handy way to throw Exceptions and in particular `RuntimeException`s or [AssertionErrors](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/AssertionError.html). Though both declare that something very unexpected has taken place, runtime exceptions are not to be used for testing. More, assertions lie **inside** the source code while unit tests examine the code's behavior on runtime from the client's point of view proving better insight on what might happen when the software is released. While it's good to "assert" some conditions in the source code, overdoing it leads to chaos (a code foul of assertions, admittedly does not look very good).

Finally, `System.out.println()` is used by many along with unit tests to output information to the developer and, alas, this is a very common practice among developers probably because it's very easy to do so. In my humble opinion, this is a bad use of the System's output (whether we are talking about Java or any other programming language). So even in the case we need to do something quick and dirty is better to use the `System.err` for debugging or much better use a logger (e.g. SLF4J). My main point though here is that it's very impotent that the developer will go through every singly output of the unit tests to check if it looks as expected (Imaging doing so with tens of unit tests).

So unit test, assertions and System.out/System.err have all their own purpose. Nothing obliges of course the programmer to follow some specific "musts" or go always by the manual (and I don't think anyone really does) but it's good to find those practices that will pay back in the long term and offer you a well-organized and bug-free (as much as possible) source code. And as far as I am concerned, unit tests definitely help towards that direction despite that it's sometimes boring to write an exhaustive test.

Comment: ...but: does this answer the question?

Comment: From my point of view yes, it does (extensively)!